# Intersection which is not equidimensional

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I would like to find an explicit example of two irreducible **complex** algebraic subvarieties $X,Y\subset \mathbb{C}^n$ such that the irreducible components of $X\cap Y$ are not equidimensional, i.e. there exists irreducible components $Z_1, Z_2$ of $X\cap Y$, such that $\dim Z_1 \neq \dim Z_2$.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the variety defined by the ideal $(xv-uy, xw-uz, yw-zv)$ in 6-space. This is a four dimensional variety.Intersect it with the linear space $x=y=0$. Then, it will have 2 components, defined by $(x,y,u,v)$ a 2-dimensional variety and $(x,y,z)$ a 3-dimensional variety.

Comment: Nice example, +1.  Would you mind saying something about how you came up with it?  It looks like you took the (affine cone over the) Segre embedding of two copies of $\mathbb{P}^2$ and then projected away from some of the coordinates.  I guess by considering the dimensions, it's not a complete intersection...

Comment: @Quasicoherent It is the Segre of $\mathbb{P}^2\times\mathbb{P}^1$. Then you take a $\mathbb{P}^2\times\{x\}$ and $\{y\}\times\mathbb{P}^1$. These are linear subspaces under the embedding and since they meet (at $(y,x)$), they are contained in a 3-space and in fact this 3-space intersects the variety precisely in that plane and that line.